# I want to Use laravel to create chat using websocket with mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, websocket, redis, laravel-echo

I think I'm going to use Laravel Echo and Redis or pusher, can't I do that with MySQL?
Or is there a good tutorial on how to avoid using Laravel Echo?

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this example might be interesting, it uses redis, you could also use any db https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server

Comment: Laravel echo, redis and socket.io is what you want. Nothing wrong with laravel echo.

Comment: This is the instruction of my unreasonable boss